# How to convert time-series dataset into a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have four lists as follows where each `node` has 6 time-series values ordered based on the years from 2001-2006 (i.e. `2001`, `2002`, `2003`, `2004`, `2005`, `2006`).

```
mylist1 = [['node1', 3.2, 4.5, 6.8, 7.6, 8.8, 9.6], ['node2', 6.2, 9.5, 2.8, 8.6, 1.8, 8.6]]

mylist2 = [['node1', 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9], ['node2', 6, 9, 2, 8, 1, 8]]

mylist3 = [['node1', 3.6, 4.2, 6.6, 7.8, 8.9, 9.5], ['node2', 6.8, 9.9, 2.5, 8.2, 1.6, 8.2]]

mylist4 = [['node1', 2, 5, 8, 6, 8, 6], ['node2', 2, 5, 8, 6, 8, 6]]
```

I want to convert the above 4 lists into the following pandas dataframe.

```
id     year    mylist1  mylist2  mylist3  mylist4
node1  2001    3.2      3        3.6       2
node1  2002    4.5      4        4.2       5
node1  2003    6.8      6        6.6       8
node1  2004    7.6      7        7.8       6
node1  2005    8.8      8        8.9       8
node1  2006    9.6      9        9.5       6
node2  2001    6.2      6        6.8       2
node2  2002    9.5      9        9.9       5
node2  2003    2.8      2        2.5       8
node2  2004    8.6      8        8.2       6
node2  2005    1.8      1        1.6       8
node2  2006    8.6      8        8.2       6
```

I converted my lists to pandas dataframes as follows.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(mylist1))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(mylist2))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(list(mylist3))
df4 = pd.DataFrame(list(mylist4))
```

However, I am not sure how I can concatenate these dataframes to obtain my vertical alignment of time-series as shown above.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: pd.DataFrame(mylist1+mylist2+mylist3+mylist4) should work, didn't saw the year data

Comment: @iamklaus actually the values in the lists are in the order of years (i.e. 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try :

```py
from functools  import reduce
lists = [mylist1, mylist2, mylist3, mylist4]
dfs = [pd.DataFrame(mylist).melt(id_vars = [0]).loc[:,[0, 'value']].rename(columns = \
                                    {"value":'mylist{}'.format(i+1), 0:'id'}) \
                                   for i, mylist in enumerate(lists)]
df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right.pop(right.columns[1]).to_frame(),\
                                             left_index= True, right_index = True), dfs)
df_final = df_final.sort_values('id').reset_index(drop = True)
```

The result is as follows :

```py
    id  mylist1 mylist2 mylist3 mylist4
0   node1   3.2 3   3.6 2
2   node1   4.5 4   4.2 5
4   node1   6.8 6   6.6 8
6   node1   7.6 7   7.8 6
8   node1   8.8 8   8.9 8
10  node1   9.6 9   9.5 6
1   node2   6.2 6   6.8 2
3   node2   9.5 9   9.9 5
5   node2   2.8 2   2.5 8
7   node2   8.6 8   8.2 6
9   node2   1.8 1   1.6 8
11  node2   8.6 8   8.2 6
```

you could then add year afterwards by doings :

```py
year_col = [2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006]
df_final['year'] = year_col * 2
```

Comment: Hi, I was able to run your code now. It seems like I get an error at the line `df final = reduce()` as `ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`. Is there a way to resolve this issue? :)

Comment: That's kind of weird,I tested it,  it runs just fine, what version of pandas do you run it on ?

Comment: I edited my answer, maybe it would work now on your version of pandas too, I converted the `right.pop(right.columns[1])` to a dataframe instead before merging

Comment: Thank you for the comments. The pandas version I am using is `'0.23.4'`. What is yours? :)

Comment: mine is `0.24.2`, but I guess it would work now that I've edited it

Comment: glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

I use `MultiIndex` for index. Create multiindex from name of each `mylist` and `node`. Create a dataframe using concat of all mylists and assign index as multiindex. Finally, unstack, drop unwanted column, transpose, sort_index and drop unwanted index level:

```
l1 = ['mylist1','mylist2','mylist3','mylist4']
l2 = ['node1', 'node2']
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([l1, l2])

(pd.DataFrame(mylist1+mylist2+mylist3+mylist4, index=idx).drop(0,1).unstack().T 
            .sort_index(level=1).droplevel(0))
Out[283]:
       mylist1  mylist2  mylist3  mylist4
node1      3.2      3.0      3.6      2.0
node1      4.5      4.0      4.2      5.0
node1      6.8      6.0      6.6      8.0
node1      7.6      7.0      7.8      6.0
node1      8.8      8.0      8.9      8.0
node1      9.6      9.0      9.5      6.0
node2      6.2      6.0      6.8      2.0
node2      9.5      9.0      9.9      5.0
node2      2.8      2.0      2.5      8.0
node2      8.6      8.0      8.2      6.0
node2      1.8      1.0      1.6      8.0
node2      8.6      8.0      8.2      6.0
```

Comment: Hi, I get an error saying `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'droplevel'`. Is there a way to resolve this issue? :)

Comment: It means your pandas version < 0.24. In this case, you need to change `droplevel(0)` to `reset_index(level=0, drop=True)`

Answer (score 1):

another approach

```
df = pd.DataFrame(mylist1+mylist2+mylist3+mylist4).sort_values(0).reset_index(drop=True)
first_half = a.loc[:3,1:].T
second_half = a.loc[4:,1:].T
first_half['id'] = 'node1'
first_half['year'] = np.arange(2001,2007)
second_half['id'] = 'node2'
second_half['year'] = np.arange(2001,2007)

master = pd.concat([first_half,second_half]).reset_index(drop=True)
master = master[['id','year',0,1,2,3]]
master.columns = ['id','year','mylist1','mylist2','mylist3','mylist4']
##master
```

**Output**

```
       id  year  mylist1  mylist2  mylist3  mylist4
0   node1  2001      3.2      3.0      3.6      2.0
1   node1  2002      4.5      4.0      4.2      5.0
2   node1  2003      6.8      6.0      6.6      8.0
3   node1  2004      7.6      7.0      7.8      6.0
4   node1  2005      8.8      8.0      8.9      8.0
5   node1  2006      9.6      9.0      9.5      6.0
6   node2  2001      6.2      6.0      6.8      2.0
7   node2  2002      9.5      9.0      9.9      5.0
8   node2  2003      2.8      2.0      2.5      8.0
9   node2  2004      8.6      8.0      8.2      6.0
10  node2  2005      1.8      1.0      1.6      8.0
11  node2  2006      8.6      8.0      8.2      6.0
```